# *ignore* C++ and C# How to display percentage in a command line

Tags: c#, c++, command-line

When I make a program where the progress is shown in the command line,
how do I make 1 line which increases (or decreases) when the progress grows?

So that you don't get this:

```
Progress: 1%
Progress: 2%
Progress: 3%
Progress: 4%
Progress: 5%
Progress: 6%
```

But this:

```
Progress: PROGRESS%
```

So 1 single line for the whole operation

Can someone explain to me how this works?

Comment: Which language? c++ or c#?

Comment: Not sure if there is a standards-compatible cross-platform way in both languages. What happens if you use '\r' without '\n' after it?

Comment: You can use curses for *nix systems, for windows I don't know.

Comment: @luiscubal This works on *nix, no idea on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way is to write lines that DON'T end with a Newline (`\n`) character, but a Carriage Return (`\r`) instead, so they can be overwritten. For compatibility with the most platforms, one must manually flush the standard output after doing so, on pain of the line not being displayed.

Comment: Would this work if you had say 5 lines of formatted text and want to overwrite them all?

Comment: I'm afraid not, because you can't go back up one line with this method: You can only go the the start of the current line. For *that*, see Duncan Smith's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C# use Console.SetWindowPosition

In C++ (Windows, I presume) use SetConsoleCursorPosition.

(For non-Windows C++ use the ncurses library).

Answer (score 0):

You try with following

```
 Console.Write("\rProgress-{0}%   ", progvalue);
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to clear the console.  In C# you can do this with `Console.Clear`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.clear.aspx

In C++ I think you would do the following:

`system("cls");`

You should have a function which rewrites all the text to the console after each clear with the updated values.

Comment: When I have a progress bar I certainly don't want my whole console to be cleared, because I need to see what happened before. -1

Comment: Not if you internally are storing the state and rewriting it each time.  For complex ASCII charts or graphics like for example [this memtest console](http://www.memtest.org/pics/amd64-big.gif) I am pretty sure clearing the console is pretty standard.

Comment: It's not much different than how in any Windows control you would store the state in variables and repaint the entire control every time on each WM_PAINT.

Comment: Not saying you would do this if you just wanted to rewrite 1 line, but it's a valid approach for complex ASCII formatting.

Comment: Yet OP explicitly asks for 1 line.

Comment: You do realize that on StackOverflow answers are not just for the OP?  They are for everyone to find in years to come with similar search terms.  An asker might search for "Console.Clear" looking for alternatives and find "Console.SetWindowPosition" in this thread, or vice-versa could happen.  It is best to answer with all solutions.

Comment: How can I make it clear to you? In a console, you run a bunch of different programs, bound together usually with a shell script. Then comes your program that needs to display a progress bar. How is it going to keep the previous programs' output which you know nothing about if you're clearing the screen? Sorry if I am a pain, but this does *not* answer OP's question.

Comment: You do realize that on StackOverflow answers are not just for the OP?

Comment: Oh gosh. You *do* realize that on SO answers are meant to answer OP's question, right? No need to answer me, that's just a rhetorical question. I certainly won't answer back anyway.